# MediaWiki: adjusting image to screen size

Tags: css, mediawiki, image-size

I want to put a banner on the top of the main page in my MediaWiki site. The problem is that when I set up the size of the banner (e.g. `[[image:banner.png | 1400px]]` ) it will show correctly on my widescreen monitor but when using a device with a different screen size (e.g. a 4/3 monitor, a tablet or a phone) the image extends to the right of the page as it is too large to show on said screen or the screen will display only a part of the image.

What I want to do is make the banner adjust to the width of the screen used, the same way a table's width is adjusted to, say, 100% and to display correctly on all screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

As [Help:Images](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Help:Images) explains, there are several methods in image markup to customise thumbnail size, including `upright` which respects user preferences.

As for what you ask, only a surrounding div `width` can achieve it, so you must set a bigger image than needed and then resize. Not so efficient for bandwidth but works, see [Wikivoyage example](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Lyon):

```
<div class="topbanner">
[[File: Banner Lyon Saint Jean.jpg|frameless|1800px|]]
</div>
```

with MediaWiki:Common.css having

```
.topbanner img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9;
}
```